# Paperclip styles not being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Paperclip works fine in my rails 3 app, but its only creating one file.  The original file is 1600x1280, and only one file sized to 200 is being created.

```
  :styles => { :preview => "500x500>", :full => "100%", :pdf_thumbnail => ["200x200>", :jpg] },
```

The style being created is pdf_thumbnail.  And, for some reason paperclip is not creating an original.

```
 paperclip (3.3.0)
 rails 3.2.8
 heroku, s3
```

Has something changed in 3.3.0?  Anyone know why paperclip is not creating the files?

Comment: I thought you had to add has_attached_file :photo to your model.rb file then has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :full => "100%", :small => "150x150>" }

Comment: Ya, my set up is - has_attached_file :document, :styles => ...

Comment: I added rmagick gem...no change

Comment: what happens if you explicitly say :full => ["100%", :jpg]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am embarrassed to admin I have paperclip in six projects and I was able to overlook this.  I did not have a style in the path.  Therefor, each style was being created but was overwriting the previously created image (because they all would have the same name).  As a result only one image with the last style was being created.  Adding :style to my path fixed everything allowed each image to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Try add rmagick gem in your gemfile

Comment: try change 300x300> -> 300x300! OR 300x300#

Comment: I played with the image styles (like Cezinha recommended)...nothing seems to be changing anything.  PaperClip is not creating an original, and not creating styles.  I agree with Cezinha that it seems like rmagick is not doing its job.